# How to export a PDF file from Indesign. (text should be non selectable and file size should be smaller)

Tags: pdf, adobe-indesign

I tried to export a PDF from indesign CC3, with "smallest  File size" preset. Its giving me very good result, the exported PDF file size is 2.8mb

But when I converted text to outline, the PDF size increased to 15Mb.

I have tried "Transparency Flattener Presets", to create a PDF (non selectable text)

Please help me if you have any solution for this.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want the text to be non-selectable? Of course, outlined text is bigger, and rendering quality is inferior (because with that, you successfully killed all the hints from the font file). It may be much better to set appropriate security to the document.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a PDF? You can open the first PDF in PS to flatten the text and save as JPEG for lower file size. I do this all the time to email proofs.

If you still want it to be a PDF, you can place the flattened JPEG file back into InD (hide all other layers) and save as PDF again. Just be sure to Crop To: Trim Box if you have bleeds. Should be smaller file size. Good luck!